# Generate self-signed certificate with specific cipher suites using OpenSSL?

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl, x509

I am trying to generate a self-signed server certificate with specific cipher suites supported:

- TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

How should I proceed to generate the specific cert? I saw that most guides follow this command:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -out MyCertificate.crt -keyout MyKey.key
```

Should I be changing the -sha256 parameter?

Comment: X.509 certificates don't include cipher suites at the moment. They may one day, but not today. In contrast, I believe OpenSSH certificates does allow one to assert ciphers. Cipher suites are configured at the client and server, and negotiated during the SSL/TLS handshake.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about server certificates then in order to support those two ciphersuites your server will need an RSA certificate. The command that you listed will do that and will give you what you need.

> Should I be changing the -sha256 parameter?

No, there is no need to do that. That specifies the digest to be used when signing the certificate. This is not related to the digest specified in the ciphersuite (SHA1).

Answer (score -1):

X.509 certificate has nothing to do with cipher suite support. They are have no relations between each other. Certificate is used to authenticate entities (client and server). Symmetric algorithm selection is certificate-independent process and is handled by TLS server/client library separately.

Comment: Thanks, is there a link to have a good read on this certificate, cipher suite thing? So the certificate is used to authenticate  while the cipher is used to encrypt the transmission?

Comment: `So the certificate is used to authenticate while the cipher is used to encrypt the transmission?` exactly. Here is some reading: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/90428/117761 (especially, last paragraph)

Comment: This is not correct. The last paragraph in the linked page is specifically referring to *client* certificates which do no have a link to the ciphersuite. However this is *not* the case for server certificates. @user990639 does not specify whether a client or server certificate is required - but client certificates are much less common than server certificates, so I assume the latter. In that case the type of key in the server certificate must match the authentication algorithm in the ciphersuite.  The two ciphersuites in the question both use RSA, and therefore an RSA server cert is needed.